# Angular 6 adding custom header

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

Hi I am trying to add custom header through http interceptor, following is my code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { StorageService } from 'src/app/services/storage-service';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthorizationHeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(private storageService:StorageService ){}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let authToken = this.storageService.getAuthorizationToken();        
    const authReq = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authToken)
    });

    return next.handle(authReq);
    }
}
```

with above code I am getting 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'. However with following changes the error goes away, but it does not set authorization header.

```
const authReq = req.clone();
authReq.headers.set('authorization',authToken);
```

what could be the problem in code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

personnally I use setHeaders and not headers

```
  //here you add the bearer in every request
  addAuthentication(req: HttpRequest<any>): HttpRequest<any> {
    const headers: any = {};
    const authToken = this.userStore.getToken(); // get the token from a service
    if (authToken) {
      headers['authorization'] = authToken; // add it to the header
      req = req.clone({
        setHeaders: headers
      });
    }
    return req;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @xrobert35, I forgot to add if(authToken) condition in my code, which was causing the problem when the authToken was undefined.